# Generic named key/value groups in C# app.config/web.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I need to add to my application a capability to read key/value info from config file, where they are stored in a hierarchical structure:

```
<appSettings>
<keygroup key="group1">
  <add key="host" value="host.address"/>
  <add key="login" value="login.name"/>
  <add key="password" value="pwd"/>
  <keygroup key="nested1">
    <add key="GroupsCanBe" value="Nested, too"/>
  </keygroup>
</keygroup>
<keygroup key="group2">
  <add key="host" value="host.address"/>
  <add key="login" value="login.name"/>
  <add key="password" value="pwd"/>
</keygroup>
</appSettings>
```

I am aware I can create custom sections under , by declaring the element name and linked class under , but I hoped there is some existing class that already does this.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code for [ConfigurationManager](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs,cfa8b7126ec13177,references) and AppSettings is declared as *NameValueCollection*

The summary comment of *NameValueCollection* says

> "Represents a collection of associated System.String keys and
>   System.String values that can be accessed either with the key or with
>   the index."

So by using AppSettings you can not have a hierarchical structure. The extensibility point of the configuration files is creating a custom configSection, as you are already aware of. appSettings out of the box is just a plain key-value collection

Comment: Ok, but perhaps you know how to introduce custom section that has a "key" attribute, and can be retrieved by this attribute's value?

Comment: I think I was confused by the appSettings example. Could you please update the question with how you want the app.config look like and how you'd like to consume the settings in that file? I'm not sure we are on the same page at the moment. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh I see, the appSettings element is for appSettings-related child elements and nothing extra. So perhaps I have to build my own XML data processor that can access hierarchical structures by name. Or perhaps there is some good class available for this already.